# Getting name of the variable for class in groovy

Tags: groovy

I am using Groovy Expando class to hold some properties and methods. I want to prevent accidental setting of the same property multiple times such as below

```
e = new Expando()
e.var1 = 'abc'
e.var1 = 'cde'
```

In order to do that I created a new class that extends Expando like below

```
class MyExpando extends Expando {
void setProperty(String property, Object newValue) {
   if(this.getProperty(property)){
      throw new RuntimeException("duplicate declaration of $property in  ${this.class.name}")
   } else {
   super.setProperty(property, newValue)
    }
   } 
 }
```

This works so it throws RuntimeException but I want the error message to be like **Duplicate property var1 in e**. Now the question is how to get **e**

Comment: Not sure if it's possible without any hacks. You need to get the access to field of type `MyExpando` from `MyExpando`, so `MyExpando` should have known about all fields of its type. The solution will also differ in groovy script and groovy class.